# How to add an action item between Delete and Refresh in DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have just created a module and all is good. I add an action to the menu with this code...

Public ReadOnly Property ModuleActions() As DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.Actions.ModuleActionCollection

Implements DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.IActionable.ModuleActions
Get

Dim Actions As New Entities.Modules.Actions.ModuleActionCollection

Actions.Add(
GetNextActionID,
"My New Action",
Entities.Modules.Actions.ModuleActionType.EditContent,
"",
"",
EditUrl(),
False,
SecurityAccessLevel.Edit,
True,
False
)

Return Actions

End Get

End Property

This places a third edit option that looks like a pencil and when I mouse over it, my new menu option shows up. How do I get it so that my new menu option appears between the Delete and Refresh action items in the list under the cog icon.

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm not sure you can customize the 2 existing systems menus. I can't remember if I've already seen that.

Comment: In that case, how do I add another action in another 'hover over' instance so there are 4 horizontal 'hover over' options? Is that possible?